# Passing a faulty object as a parameter makes Java completely ignore method calls without an error statement. What can cause this?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, runtime-error

I'm working on a minecraft plugin where I'm using [CommandAPI](https://commandapi.jorel.dev/) to add commands.

I've registered a command for opening a menu, and in order to open this menu, I am doing a call to my InterfaceManager class, which has an open() method that takes some parameters for which interface to open.

However, when executing the command ingame, it appears to me as if the open() method is completely being ignored. By that I mean that the line InterfaceManager.open() might as well have been commented out, because that's how the code is being treated.

This is extremely confusing to me, as this is not at all behaviour that I am used to from Java. Which is why I would be extremely delighted if someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is how I have defined the code for executing the command:

```
    executesPlayer((sender, args) -> {
        Main.logger().info("[MenuCommand] player executes menu command");
        Main.logger().info("[MenuCommand] test123");
        Main.test();
        InterfaceManager.open(DefaultInterfaceLabels.MAIN_MENU, sender);
        Main.logger().info("[MenuCommand] InterfaceManager open() called");
    });
```

Here is the InterfaceManager.open() method:

```
public static void open(InterfaceLabel<?> label, Player player, String... args) {
    Main.logger().info("[InterfaceManager] test123");
    Main.logger().info("[InterfaceManager] opening interface: " + label + " " + player);
    build(label, player, args, true);
}
```

These are the results in the console after doing /menu:

```
[10:50:09] [Server thread/INFO]: Pizzanakin issued server command: /menu
[10:50:09] [Server thread/INFO]: [MenuCommand] player executes menu command
[10:50:09] [Server thread/INFO]: [MenuCommand] test123
[10:50:09] [Server thread/INFO]: [Main] testing method call
[10:50:10] [atlantispool housekeeper/DEBUG]: [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] atlantispool - Before cleanup stats (total=6, active=0, idle=6, waiting=0)
```

The test() method in the Main class is simply there to confirm that the code is capable of executing static methods defined in other classes.

I would expect that, regardless of any errors that would exist at later points in the code, that it would at least print "[InterfaceManager] test123" and then the following line which shows the given parameters. But the whole method is skipped, as if it's simply not being called. I've never seen this type of behaviour before, which is why I'm very confused.

Actually, after a bit more testing, I made these changes:

```
public static void test() {
    Main.logger().info("[InterfaceManager] testing method call");
}

public static void open(InterfaceLabel<?> label, Player player, String... args) {
    Main.logger().info("[InterfaceManager] test123");
    Main.logger().info("[InterfaceManager] opening interface: " + label + " " + player);
    //build(label, player, args, true);
}
```

Basically, moving the test() method from Main to InterfaceManager, just to check if it's possible to execute generic static methods from that class. Then I also commented out the build() method, just in case there are any errors there.

The resulting logs of this are:

```
[11:10:04] [Server thread/INFO]: Pizzanakin issued server command: /menu
[11:10:04] [Server thread/INFO]: [MenuCommand] player executes menu command
[11:10:04] [Server thread/INFO]: [MenuCommand] test123
[11:10:04] [Server thread/INFO]: [InterfaceManager] testing method call
[11:10:10] [atlantispool housekeeper/DEBUG]: [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] atlantispool - Before cleanup stats (total=6, active=0, idle=6, waiting=0)
```

The only conclusion I can draw from this is, I guess something is wrong with the parameters that are being passed to the open() method? Because that is basically the only difference at this point between test() and open(), other than that they are just both printing statements and nothing more. However, it's a shame it's not providing me with an error where I can actually find the details of what's going wrong.

I checked this by adding another method:

```
public static void opentest(Player player, String... args) {
    Main.logger().info("[InterfaceManager] test123");
    Main.logger().info("[InterfaceManager] opening interface: " + player);
    //build(label, player, args, true);
}
```

And calling it as such:

```
executesPlayer((sender, args) -> {
        Main.logger().info("[MenuCommand] player executes menu command");
        Main.logger().info("[MenuCommand] test123");
        InterfaceManager.test();
        InterfaceManager.opentest(sender, "test");
        InterfaceManager.open(DefaultInterfaceLabels.MAIN_MENU, sender);
        Main.logger().info("[MenuCommand] InterfaceManager open() called");
    });
```

Now I got these results:

```
[11:21:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Pizzanakin issued server command: /menu
[11:21:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [MenuCommand] player executes menu command
[11:21:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [MenuCommand] test123
[11:21:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [InterfaceManager] testing method call
[11:21:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [InterfaceManager] test123
[11:21:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [InterfaceManager] opening interface: CraftPlayer{name=Pizzanakin}
[11:21:41] [atlantispool housekeeper/DEBUG]: [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] atlantispool - Before cleanup stats (total=6, active=0, idle=6, waiting=0)
```

That basically confirms my assumptions that it will have to do with how InterfaceLabel is set up. If anyone could give an insight as to what could be wrong with the class, that would be appreciated. Although I understand if that's difficult, because I haven't shared the class files. Considering this is quite a large project, and I doubt someone would actually spend the energy to go through all of my classes just to find the problem, I'm just looking for a hunch to focus my attention to.

Thanks in advance!